# Calling XSpi_Transfer from within gpio interrupt context

Tags: fpga, xilinx

In a microblaze environment on a virtex 5:

I have a situation where I need to do a spi transaction (XSpi_Transfer) to read from an external chip (mcp2515) in repsonse to an interrupt.  The interrupt is triggered using the gpio interrupt feature of XGpio interface.

The problem I'm having is that the XSpi_Transfer hangs when called from interrupt context.  Any hints on whether using XSpi from an interrupt is possible or not?  I presume the issue is that the low level mechanism of the XSpi uses interrupts to perform low level fifo handling.

Comment: Does the SPI transfer work without the interrupt stuff? Is the SPI properly initiated? Try to poll the GPIO pin in a loop and do the SPI transfer there.